# Best Mean Square approximation.

Tags: numerical-methods

I am trying to teach myself about the best mean square approximation of a function. I can't seem to find much informtion on internet.

Could someone help me go through the best mean square approximation of a function $f= \dfrac{1}{x+2}$. It would be easier to understand it through this (r any other example.

Comment: The best mean square approximation usually applies to fitting a certain type of curve (often a straight line), with some unknown parameters, to a set of given data points. Your question makes no sense from this point of view. Where is your data? What kind of function e.g. $f(x) = \frac{1}{ax+b}$ do you want to fit?

Comment: Another notion of best fit is to approximate a given function as a projection onto a subspace of functions generated by a linear combination of other functions. Again, your question makes no sense in this context either.